# Collatz Question

Tags: discussion

I voted to close [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139073/beyond-collatz-a-5n1-conjecture) about a "5n+1" version of the Collatz conjecture because it appears to be entirely unmotivated, with no heuristics and not even any substantial numerical evidence.

I don't see the difference in principle between this question and "How many solutions are there to this diophantine equation I've just randomly typed?".

On the other hand, I can imagine this question generating some interesting answers (e.g. applying ideas from Conway's argument that Collatz-like problems are in general undecideable).    So I'm opening this thread in case others want to comment.

Comment: I have checked this conjecture by a heuristic applying a mathematuica program and it works. I will pdate the question with the mathematica program so you can test the heuristic by yourself.

Comment: Abstarctly I agree. However there are many such questions, some of them even very well received. And, this variant is likely not true (neither is it original), and so I decide it would be simplest to give this as answer. (Also it is weekend and I felt slightly bored.)

Comment: The OP's attempt to pass off a few lines of Mathematica code as a "heuristic" now convinces me that the question should be closed.

Comment: And, I better had not answered it as somehow I misread it all the time. Sorry for the noise (to those that might mind)!

Comment: Steven we run here with my colleagues through the code tests from $1$ up to one million integers as starting points. The conjecture still holds. quid's response is excellent and supports the heuristic that even a test up to $1000$ would be strong enough. Thanks for your support.

Comment: al-Hwarizmi:  I do not think that the word "heuristic" means what you think it means.

Comment: As I said I can see and (abstractly) agree this question might be off-topic, however it is not clear to me what should make it so different than say http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120511/why-do-primes-dislike-dividing-the-sum-of-all-the-preceding-primes for one of many example (which is at +15 no downvote and a *massively* upvoted answer).

Comment: @quid: Ugh ... . I'd say it's not so different, but I really don't see why there are THAT many upvotes on such question and an answer which probably almost everyone of us could have given.

Comment: @Stefan Kohl thanks for your comment.

Comment: Voting on MO is so weird sometimes...

Comment: @ToddTrimble Less so if you observe voting out in the "real world" (sad to say)